# Create Planner Plan from Graph API "You Do not have the required permissions"

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-planner

I have built a flow that uses an HTTP call to the graph after getting an authorization from oauth2. I kept getting intermittent failures so I tried a test batch of 25 and 44% of the runs failed with the error " You do not have the required permissions to access this item, or the item may not exist."

The only thing different for the tests were the name of the plan being created, each one gets a group provisioned first then the final step is a planner plan.

Screenshot of the failures"
[Image1 All Runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKFr4.png)

Screenshot of the error:
[Image 2 Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQQrO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the failure in the screenshot is because the caller is not a member of the group (which is different from being an owner). Given that the failure is intermittent I assume your flow does add the user as a member? The member updates to the group are not immediately visible to other services. So:

- Make sure you add the user as a member.
- In case of 403, retry a few times with a few seconds delay.

Unfortunately this is currently the only way to work around the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The flow does add the user as a member and 66% of the time the flow works fine, it's very intermittent that it's failing. Also the tests were done with the same user and data being passed to the flow except the title which just sequentially went project001, project002, project003 ect.